# How to handle lag in replicat in oracle goldengate while running housekeeping scheduler jobs in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-golden-gate

A scheduler job runs at 11PM every night to delete around 500,000 records in Source Oracle Database 12c. During this time, replication lag on target database suddenly increases from 4 seconds to 900 seconds and keeps on increasing to 7500 seconds till 3AM(End time of scheduler job). After that it lag starts to gradually decrease and reaches to 4 seconds again at 4AM. Is this a normal behaviour of Oracle Goldengate when running housekeeping scheduler jobs in production databases?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that the lag is caused by the 500k rows delete operation.

You need to check where does the lag come from. You might use the heartbeat build in functionality in OGG. It helps very much. Depending on the source of the lag:

1. Extract: If the operation goes in one DML operation - divide it into smaller chunks.
2. Network/hardware: Make some network tuning, increase the packet size. Check the hardware load.
3. Replicat: If your smaller chunks are still applied slowly - try to use the parallel form of replication, like Parallel Replicat, Integrated Replicat. Or, you might also consider the Coordinated Replicat mode if this delete can be run transaction-independent.

Comment: Commit is performed after deletion of 1500 rows, Can this be the issue which is causing replication slow? Extract process is running fine.

Comment: Also please explain how parallel or coordinated replicate will help here when we perform bulk deletion. We are already using integrated replicate(OGG version 12.2.0.1).

Comment: What is slow? Is the trail populated fast and the lag comes from the Replicat? Where does the lag appear? Using Coordinated Replicat is very tricky. It can break your transactions into peaces. You have to know exactly what you are doing if you want to use this option.